# How to install private typings file?

Tags: npm-install, typescript-typings

In a project of mine I use a typings file to help developers writing their script code. For that reason I manually added the file @types/myapp/index.d.ts in the node_modules folder of that project. This works pretty well but gets in the way when running `npm install` there (it's not a node module, but I use a package.json file there to ease installing dependencies).

I added my typings file to `package.json` to keep it alive during `npm install` but that gives an E404 error. Without that dependency entry however `npm install` removes my private typings file.

So, how can I make `npm install` to either leave alone my (manually copied) typings file or install it from a local file?

I tried to install it via `typings install --global --save file:../<path>/index.d.ts` which created a typings.json file with a `globalDependencies` entry, but that doesn't work in vscode (no code completion with stuff from this typings file). As I'm on TS 2.4.1 already I guess this is no longer supported.